# android - How to open and retrieve data from database which copied from sqlite database browser database?

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm new to android development. here i m copying my database from SQLite Database Browser to my system database. But when i try to open that newly created database.. i gets an error..
here is my Code

```
DBAdapter.java

public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{


    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.xyz.app.demo/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "QuestionsDB";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 




    private final Context myContext;


    public DBAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{


            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }


    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }




    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor getAllTitles()
    {
    return myDataBase.query("Qus", new String[] {
    "_id",
    "quesion",
    "XCol",
    "Ycol",
    "option",
    "intern",
    "answer",
    "weight"},
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);
    }
```

and Also
questionform.java

```
 public class questionform extends Activity{


    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
       {
          super.onCreate(icicle);
          setContentView(R.layout.qus_screen);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

          db.openDataBase();

          Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();

          if (c.moveToFirst())
          {
              do 
              {
                  DisplayTitle(c);

              } while (c.moveToNext());


          }
          db.close();
       }

         private void DisplayTitle(Cursor c) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(questionform.this,c.getString(1),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
}
```

---

**Update**

new code for questionform.java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
       {
          super.onCreate(icicle);
          setContentView(R.layout.qus_screen);

          final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);


          try {
            db.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }

          db.openDataBase();

          Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();

          if (c.moveToFirst())
         {
              do 
              {
                  DisplayTitle(c);

              } while (c.moveToNext());


          }
          db.close();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

call this twice as follows

```
final DBAdapter db ;
try{
 db = new DBAdapter(this);

      db.openDataBase();
}catch(Exception e)
{ db = new DBAdapter(this);

      db.openDataBase();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseAssets extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String DB_PATH = null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "androidDb.db";
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "Tbl_Users";
    public static final String TABLE_Product = "Tbl_Product";
    // TABLE_CONTENT

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    public DatabaseAssets(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        // DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" +
        // "databases/";
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
                            | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
                            | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
                        | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
                        | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // return cursor
    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
            String orderBy) {
        return myDataBase.query(TABLE_Product, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);

    }
}
```